# MongoDB daily data inside array

Tags: mongodb

this might be a dumb question but I'm kinda new to MongoDB so let's give it a try.

I'm creating a database on MongoDB that will be storing inputs that will be entered every five minutes. This database in an SQL format should return something like this: [image]

The main problem comes here, I don't know If I should create a document for each idvar with the entries of every year/month/day, will it hurt the performance if I make my JSON something like this?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"),
    "IdVar" : "60502",
    "Years" : [ 
        {
            "2015" : [ 
                {
                    "January" : [ 
                        {
                            "Date_Start" : "2015-01-01",
                            "Date_End" : "2015-01-02"
                        }
                    ],
                    "February" : [ 
                        {
                            "Date_Start" : "2015-01-01",
                            "Date_End" : "2015-01-02"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Creating a document for each `IdVar` seems to be the way to go, but I dont see the point of your `Years` field structure.
I may be mistaken, but I believe the (much simpler) following structure would allow you to achieve the same thing :`{ "IdVar": 123, "dates":[{ "start": "DD/MM/YYYY", "end": "DD/MM/YYYY"},{ "start": "DD/MM/YYYY", "end": "DD/MM/YYYY"}] }`

Comment: I would say that the main point is so I can find the data in the specified year, might've been my fault cause I was thinking like if it was an SQL query.

Comment: Mongo includes cool operators like [$year](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/year/) but also `$range`, etc for these purposes. 
Coming from the relational world, the only thing you have to be attentive of is... Not falling back into doing relational with Mongo (a.k.a. `joining` over multiple collections of documents; this is a pretty common mistake you can find over the Internet). Always make sure all your queries can me achieved in one pass only over the database !

Comment: The main problem(for me at least) is that I cannot filter when to query to only receive dates.start and not the entire array inside of dates. Forgive me father for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: Check out the answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51057062/7152435) ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Querying over nested arrays could always seems tedious in the first place.

Consider the following collection (as proposed [in the comments of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51044700/7152435)):

```
[
  {
    "IdVar": "60502",
    "dates": [
      {
        "start": new Date("2017-03-01"),
        "end": new Date("2017-04-01")
      },
      {
        "start": new Date("2018-04-01"),
        "end": new Date("2018-06-01")
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "IdVar": "1337",
    "dates": [
      {
        "start": new Date("2016-08-01"),
        "end": new Date("2016-09-01")
      },
      {
        "start": new Date("2015-04-01"),
        "end": new Date("2015-06-01")
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

You only want to retrieve the documents which have dates in, let's say, 2017. You may use the  [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator to do so:

```
db.collection.find({
  dates: {
     $elemMatch: {
        start: {
           $gte: ISODate("2017-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
           $lte: ISODate("2017-12-31T00:00:00Z")
        }
     }
  }
})
```

... but as you rightfully stated, this will return you the document in its entirety, unaltered. In many cases, this will suit your needs, by you may still want to **project** your document fields accordingly to your **query**: A simple way of putting this is to say the projection is the SQL-equivalent of `SELECT` and the query, `WHERE`.

As an example, The following will only return me the `IdVar` field of each document matching my query:

```
db.collection.find({
  dates: {
    $elemMatch: {
      start: {
        $gte: ISODate("2017-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
        $lte: ISODate("2017-12-31T00:00:00Z")
      }
    }
  }
},
// Project your document's fields here:
{
  IdVar: true
})
```

... will return:

```
[
  {
    "IdVar": "60502",
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000")
  }
]
```

Similarly to the query, you can use (nearly) all Mongo operators in the projection fields.
The [`$`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_) operator is also pretty handy when handling nested arrays. The following code will return what you need, give it a try ([MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jbyeu7x1Xzy)):

```
db.collection.find({
  dates: {
    $elemMatch: {
      start: {
        $gte: ISODate("2017-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
        $lte: ISODate("2017-12-31T00:00:00Z")
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  "dates.$": 1
})
```

Comment: This was perfect, but just a question, imagina that I have 50000 different "start" and "end" values inside the "dates" array, would it still be manageable? Or is it way too much info for just an array?

Comment: @Anion, with Mongo, the only limit is the document size, [reference here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/). And to be honest, I never ever reached those kind of limitations myself. Mongo VS. Relational is all about the trade between query performance and updatability. With this kind of structure, querying only consist in scanning the database once, which is great (No `join` which would literally kill your performances, all the required information is), but updating your documents will be a hassle compared to SQL (tbc)...

Comment: ... Example: If you have to delete some time intervals from a doc regularly, this will be far more difficult, and then there's maybe a better structure than the one you currently use. Otherwise, if you have fixed intervals, or only push new intervals to your doc; some this is totally viable.

Comment: I might not need to delete them regularly, but I need to select and insert time intervals almost every 15 to 30 minutes, I was scared of just that. I might need to think about other structure.

Comment: If I can be of assistance, sometimes nested is good, but you can roughly achieve the same thing by aggregating single documents, [reference here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/). Here is a working [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LrMR_aA8-bb) using `aggregate` and `$group` operator as a projection. I like this example because it does illustrate NoSQL compromise: Very fast queries, no ACID properties required (doc duplication here), but just imagine having to update all "IdVar" or "content" fields if you have to ! :)

Comment: If you DO have to (update those docs); and even if this literally gives me a rash, I may go for a reference, "relational-like" structure, to another collection containing the information required; and perform the join on the application level: 
`GET /events?start=xx&end=yy` and then for each event `GET /eventInfo/IdVar`
...
Not ideal but a good compromise between query efficiency and maintainability (at least you're not joining huge tables as SQL would do)